# How do you address "To", with "An" or "Zu"?

Tags: english-to-german

How would you write this in German: "To a great colleague, best of luck!"

> An einen tollen Kollegen, viel Glück!

or

> Zu einen tollen Kollegen, viel Glück!

I want to write a short message on his farewell card, or does something else sound better?

Comment: Even if *zu* were correct, it would require the dative: Zu *einem* tollen Kollegen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case,

> An

is correct.

However, you may want to write *unserem* (our) or *meinem* (my) instead, depending on the circumstances, which sounds a bit nicer and more personal:

> Unserem tollen Kollegen viel Glück!
>
> Meinem tollen Kollegen viel Glück!